# tinyMCE insert text at cursor in textbox doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, tinymce

using tinymce:
majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '4.7',

And this insert function:

```
MrScheduler.insertVariableText = function(text){
if(MrScheduler.currentEditor)
{
    //tinyMCE insert text call
    MrScheduler.currentEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, text);
    MrScheduler.emailVariableWindow.hide();
}
else
{
    //insert the text into the current field.  Only works for IE,
    //the same functionality doesn't exist in other browsers for a regular input field
    MrScheduler.currentSelectedField.focus();
    if (document.selection) {
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = text;
        MrScheduler.emailVariableWindow.hide();
    }
}
};
```

tinyMCE will not insert text into my emailFileNameField (Text field)
tinyMCE will not insert text into my emailSubjectField (Text field)
tinyMCE WILL insert text into my emailBodyField(Editor Field)

Is there a workaround to get tinyMCE to insert at cursor in a textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix that worked for me. Turns out it was not an issue with TinyMCE as TinyMCE wasn't being called at this point, but a custom "function??" was being called instead. I fixed the issue by changing the else statement as follows:

```
else
{
    //Insert text in selected field in OTHER BROWSERS 
    MrScheduler.currentSelectedField.focus();
    if (window.getSelection()) {      
        var sel = MrScheduler.currentSelectedField;
        var currText = MrScheduler.currentSelectedField.getValue().toString(); //Get any existing text
        sel.setValue(currText.toString() + text); //append to current value
        MrScheduler.emailVariableWindow.hide();
    }
}
```